# Find Normal and Tangent vectors and lines to the plane curve $x^2+2y^3=xy+4$ at $(2,1)$

Tags: calculus

Find Normal and Tangent vectors and lines to the plane curve $x^2+2y^3=xy+4$ at $(2,1)$

Having some difficulty, hoping someone can clear this up with me so I can draw on it for subsequent examples. Thanks!

Comment: First step: partial derivatives . Would you mind sharing with us what you got?

Comment: f_x (x_0,y_0) comes as 2x=y, f_y(x_0,y_0) is 6y^2=x, for the normal line, is this f_x-f_y?

And f_y-f_x for the tangent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put $f(x,y)=x^2+2y^3-xy-4$, then normal vector at $(x,y)$ would be
$$\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x},\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)=(2x-y,6y^2-x)$$
Thus the tangent vector at $(x,y)$ is $(6y^2-x,y-2x)$.

So the normal vector at $(2, 1)$ is $(3, 4)$, the tangent vector is $(4, -3)$

Another way. Let $f(x,y)=0$, then take derivative respect to $x$, then get 
$$2x+6y^2y'-y-xy'=0\Rightarrow y'=\frac{y-2x}{6y^2-x}$$
The normal and tangent vectors obtained again from above.

Comment: Aha, I understand, I had gotten y' as above but wasn't sure that i could obtain the vectors as you have done, thank you! Also, the y coordinate changes in the tangent vector because they are perpendicular?

Comment: Yes, because when 2 vectors are perpendicular, their dot product is equal to $-1$